# azure: how to access abc.cloudapp.net

Tags: azure

one colleague of mine set up a virtual machine on azure and sent me the following address: `abc.cloudapp.net`.

He then told me that I can access to the machine, but he didn't tell me how...
Now he is in vacation and I'm stuck with that address...

Here is my questions:

1. how to use the address he gave me?
2. do I need an Azure account in order to get access?
3. should I use my browser (chrome) to access, or should I download some Azure app?

Comment: First off: this fits better on SuperUser, not StackOverflow (not a programming question). Second: We don't know if it's Linux or Windows (ssh or RDP); we don't know if you have access to the Azure portal, to view open ports; we don't know if you have the username and password for the VM. As far as downloading an app - this is really a question for SuperUser (though it's basic connectivity you're talking about, and an app isn't going to help you here). There's really no way to help you here. Might consider emailing your coworker (or waiting til they return, or creating your own VM).

Comment: Thanks for your comment. Here is my situation: I'm using a windows PC trying to access an Ubuntu VM on azure. What I have is the address (abc.cloudapp.net) and username+password he gave me (I don't even have an azure account), so I'm pretty sure that I can't access  Azure portal.

Comment: Right - then this is a perfect question for SuperUser - or even Google, to find out how to connect to a Linux machine from Windows.

Answer (score 1):

Here's the document that will help you with troubleshooting what is wrong with the VM (in case you can't connect using mstsc)

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/virtual-machines-windows-troubleshoot-rdp-connection

Comment: I really don't think this can help the OP - we don't even know if they have a username/password. We know... nothing. I'd just suggest close-voting, since it's not programming related, and at this point very unclear.

Comment: well, in that case he would have to go to the portal and check all of that ;)

Answer (score 0):

If this is a virtual machine you should be able to remote desktop to it.

From a Windows based OS go to "Remote Desktop Connection" from the start menu or type `mstsc` from a Run prompt (Start--> Run or Windows Key + r)

Then type in that address and hit "Connect", you should then be prompted to enter your credentials to log onto the machine

Comment: well, if you'd try that, it appears that the VM doesn't respond, it can have firewall configured to allow for certain IP's only, but I doubt that ;)

Comment: Good call, i didnt even think of trying it myself! WIll delete my answer if it doesn't give the poster anything useful

Comment: You're assuming 1) It's Windows; 2) the OP even has credentials for the VM. We can't assume anything at this point. The question itself is off-topic anyway...